# Increment and define a range in a Time Series Data using R

Tags: r, time-series, intervals, xts, zoo

I have a time series stock price data, I want to extract data every 15 mins.
The start time and end time (logged in the column Time) are

```
start_date1 <- as.POSIXct("2016-11-01 09:00:00")
end_date2 <- as.POSIXct("2016-11-01 09:15:00")
```

Defining the interval

```
int <- new_interval(date1, date2)
```

Extracting the data from the data frame DF_spread

```
DF_spread_interval <- DF_spread[DF_spread$Time %within% int,]
```

Now want to extract the data from the series every 15 mins, where at each iteration the start_date1 will get incremented by 15 mins and the end_date2 will also get incremented by 15 mins.

The increment should stop when the end_date2 has reached the terminal point of 3:30 pm of the same day, i.e

```
end_date2 <- as.POSIXct("2016-11-01 15:30:00")
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
st <- start_date1 + seq(0, 1500, by = 60)*15
et <- end_date1 + seq(0, 1600, by = 60)*15

Map(function(x,y) {intl <- new_interval(x,y);
               DF_spread[DF_spread$Time %within% int,]},
                    st, et)
```